# How long will a certificate from a removed card work?

Tags: wcf, security, certificate, smartcard

When mounting the card in the reader a certificate will be installed in the personal store, this certificate is then used by my WCF Client Server application for communication.

If I remove the card the certificates will also be removed from the store. If Im is in the middle of a started session I will not get any exception it will continue to work just as if the card was still in the reader? Is this by design? Does it mean that the communication will work as long as I dont try to read the certificate from the store again?

BestRegards

Comment: This depends on implementation of particular CSP module provided by smartcard reader vendor.

Answer (score 0):

A certificate is a confirmed correspondence between a public key and an identity. There is no pressing need to delete the certificate when the card is removed, since this public key may still be useful to verify signed messages of that sender. X.509 certificates also have expiration dates to address the removal topic, similarly revocation lists. So while the private key (depending on configuration) may just be used as long as card is in place, the public key may exceed this by far.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these pages as well:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404287(v=ws.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404288(v=ws.10).aspx

And most of all, keep in mind that a smart card is usually only needed to initiate/open a session